# Casting specific observablecollection to a generic observablecollection

Tags: c#, .net, generics, collections

I would appreciate your valuable input in order solving my issue.

I have an Interface which is none generic

```
public interface IOffice
{
   ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees{ get; set; }
}
```

The 'Employee' is an entity.

```
public class Employee
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get, set}
}
```

I extend this interface in a generic abstract class, which facilitates sending any extended
type of Employee as a type parameter.
But I'm having an issue casting the specific property "Employees" to a generic "Employee" property in the abstract class like below. 
It shows compiler casting error.

```
public abstract HeadOffice<T> : IOffice
where T : Employee
{
     ObservableCollection<T> _employees = new ObservableCollection<T>();
     public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees
      { 
          get{return employees;} 
          set{employees = value;} 
      }
}
```

NOTE : This could be solved if we could change the interface into a generic 'IOffice'. But we don't have a control over the interface.

Appreciate all your feedback and do contact me if you require classifying anything with regard to the issue.

Thanks
RSF

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `ObservableCollection<T>` as if it were both covariant and contravariant in `T`. That's pretty meaningless.

Maybe you want to copy the collections (but that may be expensive!):

```
public abstract HeadOffice<T> : IOffice
where T : Employee
{
     ObservableCollection<T> _employees = new ObservableCollection<T>();
     public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees
      { 
          get
          {
              return new ObservableCollection<Employee>(_employees);
          } 
          set
          {
              _employees.Clear();
              foreach (var e in value)
              {
                  var t = e as T;
                  if (t == null)
                      throw new InvalidOperationException("...");
                  _employees.Add(t);
              }
          } 
      }
}
```

In the `set` accessor you need to check the type of each item in the collection `value`. The `foreach` could also have been done with Linq.

There are obvious problems with this solution. If someone uses the setter to pass in his own `ObservableCollection<>` where he has subscribed to the `CollectionChanged` event, because we don't actually use his object, his event subscription will not be honored. And so on.